# how to set OpenTK window icon

Tags: c#, icons, opentk

I've tried looking around and I cant figure out how to set the top-left window Icon for an OpenTK gameWindow, I'm using C# and I'm trying to set the icon to a image file on my computer.

My IDE is Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to Project > (projectname) Properties > Application

you should see a section for setting your icon

[image: Steps]

if this section is blurred out

then open the .csproj file and add `<ApplicationIcon>Path/to/file</ApplicationIcon>`

in the `<PropertyGroup>` section.

Comment: this should work for all types of c# apps

Comment: i am using visual studio code and not visual studio

Comment: oh ok my bad I will keep this up for people that are using visual studio

Comment: @Jonah-H do you have a .csproj file? if you do add <ApplicationIcon>Path/to/file</ApplicationIcon> in the <PropertyGroup> section.

Comment: yes and i tried putting your sugested code in but it didnt work

Comment: @Jonah-H can you take a screen shot of our .csproj

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `GameWindow` icon by using the `NativeWindowSettings.Icon` property.

```cs
var nativeWindowSettings = NativeWindowSettings.Default;
nativeWindowSettings.Icon = new WindowIcon(width, height, data); // data is a byte[]
```

If you want a more concrete example, I'm using `ImageSharp` to actually load the image and create the `WindowIcon`:

```
public static WindowIcon CreateWindowIcon()
{
    var image = (Image<Rgba32>)Image.Load(Configuration.Default, "./Assets/Images/Logo.png");
    image.TryGetSinglePixelSpan(out var imageSpan);
    var imageBytes = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(imageSpan).ToArray();
    var windowIcon = new WindowIcon(new OpenTK.Windowing.Common.Input.Image(image.Width, image.Height, imageBytes));

    return windowIcon;
}
```